# subsetting columns of a tibble with a character vector from another tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have two tibbles

```
>a.tibble

names other
 a      0
 c      0
 d      0

>b.tibble

a   b   c   d  e
1   1   1   1  1
1   1   1   1  1
```

I would like to use `names <- select(a.tibble,names)` to subset `b.tibble` to make `c.tibble`:

```
>c.tibble

a   c   d  
1   1   1   
1   1   1
```

It is important that I subset by `names` because in reality I have many names to subset a large tibble. This makes it so the usual `select(b.tibble,-c(b,e))` or other "manual" entry of column names is not possible.

Data

```
library(tibble)
a.tibble = tibble(names = c("a","c","d"), other = 0)
b.tibble = tibble(a = rep(1,2), b = 1, c = 1, d = 1, e = 1)
```

Comment: `b.tibble[, names(b.tibble) %in% a.tibble$names]`

Comment: I don't know how `tibble`s behave, but this works for a data.frame `b.tibble[as.character(a.tibble$names)]`

Comment: `b.tibble %>% select_(.dots = a.tibble$names)` seems to be it, though that doesn't seem like a valid way of going about things.

Comment: @Frank I struggled with `.dots` before posting. It is a confusing syntax IMO.

Comment: @Alex I agree and had to fiddle with a couple permutations before landing on this. I don't find the pipe-verse functions very friendly to programming, generally.

Answer (score 0):

@ytk had an answer that worked for me `b.tibble[, names(b.tibble) %in% a.tibble$names]`

Comment: So just `b.tibble[a.tibble$names]` didn't work for you? It works for me.